# simulate pioneer3at

Tags: ros, simulation, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new in ros and I have the following question:

I want to simulate a robot pioneer3at, but when I put in the terminal:

p2os roslaunch ... all I get is pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch

how I can simulate the robot pioneer3at?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33958/simulate-pioneer3at/) by [jmm89](https://answers.ros.org/users/2296/jmm89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find working simulation at https://github.com/allenh1/p2os (roslaunch p2os_urdf pioneer3at.gazebo.launch). But you will need current Gazebo (1.8.6) and gazebo_ros_pkgs. If using model from gazebo_models, you will not get cmd_vel and odometry topics.

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Llamazares](https://answers.ros.org/users/5313/llamazares/) on 2013-07-04**:
Thanks for your answers. ZdenekM, as you said, you need current Gazebo (1.8.6) and gazebo_ros_pkgs, but gazebo_ros_pkgs is only under ros Hydro. There is any way to work with gazebo 1.8.6 + ROS Groovy and Pioneer3AT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://goo.gl/kQEyA

https://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3277/agonzamart/) on 2013-04-18**:
Derek you know where I can find the model of a LSM200 laser instead of the hoyuko one? I can not find the model in the library of Gazebo in order to change it. I really appreciate your help.

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-04-18**:
I know one exists, I've seen it out there somewhere but I seem to have failed to save a copy and my google-foo is failing me at the moment.

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3277/agonzamart/) on 2013-04-18**:
Ok no problem, I think I so it somewhere to but I am not able to find it again. I think it was on the old gazebo model's. If you are able to find it please send me the link to it. Thanks! :)